# efficient way to search the same regular expression on multiple text

Tags: regex, perl

I have multiple texts fields every field is paragraph of text and I want to search for a specifc pattern on those fields using regular expression for example:

```
my $text1 =~/(my pattern)/ig;
my $text2 =~/(my pattern)/ig;
...
my $textn=~/(my pattern)/ig;
```

I wonder if there are an effecint way to search multiple text with the same regular expression on perl or I should use the above format?

Comment: With that code, you will get `Use of uninitialized value $text1 in pattern match (m//)` warnings, since `my $var` implies that the values are undefined.

Comment: By the way, you almost certainly want an array of text fields to begin with instead of n variables named `$text1` through `$textn`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use a topicaliser.

```
for ($text1, $text2, $textn) {
    /(my pattern)/ig && do { ... };
}
```

When you have numbered variables, it's a red flag that you should consider a compound data structure instead. With a simple array it looks nearly the same:

```
for (@texts) {
```

Comment: +1: It's amazing how many people focus on the regex part and miss the actual answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
my $pattern = qr/((?:i)my pattern)/;
my @matches;
push @matches, $text1 =~ /$pattern/g;
push @matches, $text2 =~ /$pattern/g;
push @matches, $textn =~ /$pattern/g;
```

That's about as efficient as I can think of - theoretically pre-compiles the regex once, though I'm not sure if interpolating it back into // to get the 'g' modifier undoes any of that compilation.  Of course, I also have to wonder if this is really a bottleneck, and if you're just looking at some premature optimisation.

Comment: `my @matches = map /(my pattern)/ig, $text1, $text2, ..., $textn;`

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this question depends on whether your pattern contains any variables. If it does not, perl is already smart enough to only build the RE once, as long as it's identical everywhere.

Now, if you do use variables, then @Tanktalus's answer is close, but adds unnecessary complexity, by compiling the RE an additional time.

Use this:

```
my @matches;
push @matches, $text1 =~ /((?:i)my pattern with a $variable)/o;
push @matches, $text2 =~ /((?:i)my pattern with a $variable)/o;
push @matches, $textn =~ /((?:i)my pattern with a $variable)/o;
```

### Why?

By using a variable in the RE pattern, perl is forced to re-compile for every instance, even when that variable is a pre-compiled RE as in @Tanktalus's answer. The `/o` ensures that it is only compiled once, the first time it's encountered, but it still must be compiled once for every occurence int he code.  This is because Perl has no way of knowing if $pattern changed between the different uses.

### Other considerations

In practice, as @Tanktalus also said, I suspect this is a big fat case of premature optimization.  `/o`/ only matters when your pattern contains variables (otherwise perl is smart enough to only compile once anyway!)

The far more useful reason to use a pre-compiled RE as @Tanktalus has suggested, is to improve code readability.  If you have a big hairy RE, then using $pattern everywhere will greatly improve readability, and with only a minor cost in performance (one you're not likely to ever notice).

### Conclusion

Just use `/o` for your REs if they contain variables (unless you actually need the variables to change the RE on every run), and don't worry about it otherwise.

Comment: I think that everywhere you wrote m//g you meant to instead write m//o ?

Comment: It's easier just to pre-compile it with qr// so you only specify the pattern in one place.

Comment: There's a lot of repeated structure there.

Comment: @briandfoy: Easier, but ineffective. `$x = qr/foo/; m/$x/o` results in compiling the RE twice.

Comment: I find using `/o` unnecessary even under the ancient 5.8.8 shipped with RHEL5. Perl does a good job of caching the compiled expressions so that if the variables interpolated don't change values, then the previously compiled pattern is used. So the case `/o` is designed for perl is already only compiling the pattern once. And for the odd cases where you want the variable to change but the compiled pattern to not change the next programmer will likely thank you for writing the code to make `/o` unnecessary.